# Automatically save UI related settings in Qt without user interference?

Tags: user-interface, qt4, qt4.7

Is there a way that Qt could save UI settings automatically , without calling QSettings::setValue () ? 
  e.g In a QMainWindow , save the font size of QMenu automatically

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QMainWindow has functions saveState and restoreState and also derives from QWidget save and restore geometry. However as documentation [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qmainwindow.html#restoreState) states only settings that you will be able to restore are just that: a mainwindow state and geometry. It seems unavoidable that you will have implement storage of settings for individual widgets. In the link above Qt guys give a good snippet on how to accomplish this in mainwindow derivatives.